# rename a dynamic generate file which contains BASIC

Tags: shell, filenames, rename, mv

how can i use rename of mv shell command to rename a file where i don't know the exaxt name of but which contains always de word BASIC

```
rename Ex2WebR1_0WEBSHOP01_005443_B_BASIC.XML BASIC.XML
```

I have try something like this but isn't working

```
mv 's/.*_BASIC/BASIC/g' BASIC.*
```

thank you for the help

Comment: the glob star "*" , `mv *BASIC.XML BASIC.XML` or `mv *BASIC* BASIC.XML`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is one and only one such file in the current directory, simply:

```
mv -- *_BASIC.XML BASIC.XML
```

Please, never ever parse [ls](/questions/tagged/ls) output

Answer (score 0):

Your regex attempt was heading in a valid direction and should work with a minor change if you used the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/.*_BASIC/BASIC/g' *_BASIC*
```

This assumes that your distro has a compatible version of `rename` installed (Red Hat and related distros typically do not, in my experience).

Also assumes you don’t have multiple matching files with the same extension, such that it might result in a name clash.

This variant would be most useful if you have multiple matching files with differing extensions that you wanted to rename in a single motion, otherwise you might as well stick with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590037/40482